# Github Pull Request shows two branches are identical but they are not

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I've two different branches. test and master. I worked on test branch and made some commits to it and then pushed it to the remote repot. If i go to my branch in github UI or in my console i can see all those changes, and in fact if i do 'git diff master' it even shows all the difference between master and test branch... However, when i try to create a pull request comparing test to master it says they are exactly identical, although i can see they are not... Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Can you check the commit hashes locally and on GitHub and compare them with each other?

Comment: I tried my chance but this is a huge repo that lot of people working on... And there are so many commits and i was unable to find anything useful. What should i be looking for if you elaborate more on that? @knittll

Comment: Check the commit hashes of your branches `test` and `master`. I assume you can do the same in Git when you select "compare branches" where it states that they are identical. Do you see the commit hashes on the comparison page? Do they match your local commit hashes? Are the local and remote commits identical? GitHub should also offer you to browse the history of any branch, so you can compare local and remote history, if it matches your expectations.